# python ttkbootstrap progressbar not updating when downloading YouTube Video

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, progress-bar

I am quite rusty programming wise, and not at all familiar with Python and ttkbootstrap, but I do my best.

I created a little utility too download YouTube video, and it does, basically, work, meaning it download the videos in the selected directory. BUT, the progress bar is not updating while downloading, and the percent text show 100% at the end, does not update while downloading.

I would be very thankful if you can help me to improve my code, and make things work as I believe they should...

Here is my code, so far

```
import pathlib
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkbootstrap as ttkb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
import ttkbootstrap.style 
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from pytube import YouTube


class DataEntryForm(ttkb.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, padding=(20,10))
        self.pack(fill =BOTH, expand=YES)
        
        #application variables
        self.repertoireChoisi = ttkb.StringVar()
        #self._path = pathlib.Path().absolute().as_posix()
                                                              
        #form variables
        self.URL = ttkb.StringVar(value="") 
        self.repertoire = ttkb.StringVar(value="" )     
        self.percentage_of_completion = ttkb.StringVar(value="0%")
        
        
        #form header  
        hdr_txt = "Entrez l'URL de la vidéo et le répertoire où les fichiers seront stockés"
        hdr = ttkb.Label(self, text=hdr_txt, width= 100)
        hdr.pack(fill = X, padx=10, pady=10)
        
        #form entries        
        self.create_form_entry("url", self.URL) 
        self.create_progressbar(0)
        self.create_repertoire_entry("repertoire", self.repertoire)
        self.create_buttonbox()
        
    def create_form_entry(self, label, variable):
        """Create a single form entry"""
        container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=5)

        lbl = ttkb.Label(master=container, text=label.title(), width=10)
        lbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

        ent = ttkb.Entry(master=container, textvariable=self.URL, width = 80)
        ent.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=YES)
        rep_button = ttkb.Button(
            master = container,
            text = "Télécharger",
            style=SUCCESS,
            command = self.on_download,
            width= 20
        )
        rep_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=NO)
        
    def create_repertoire_entry(self, label, variable):
        container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=5)
        lbl = ttkb.Label(master=container, text="Repertoire", width=10)
        lbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
        #self.create_form_entry("repertoire", self.repertoire)  
        ent = ttkb.Entry(master=container, width=80, textvariable=variable)        
        ent.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=NO)
        rep_button = ttkb.Button(
            master = container,
            text = "Rechercher",
            style=SUCCESS,
            command = self.on_search,
            width= 20
        )
        rep_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=NO)
                    
                    
    def create_progressbar(self, percent):
        """Create a progress bar"""
#        progress = ttkb.Frame(self,style=PRIMARY)
        #container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        progress = ttk.Progressbar(self)
        progress.pack(fill=X,expand=YES, pady=(15,10))
        # self.time_elapsed = ttk.Label(progress, text='00:00', font='Helvetica 12')
        # self.time_elapsed.pack(side='left')
        # self.time_scale = ttk.Scale(progress, orient='horizontal', style='info.Horizontal.TScale')
        # self.time_scale.pack(side='left', expand=True, padx=10)
        # self.time_remaining = ttk.Label(progress, text='00:00', font='Helvetica 12')
        # self.time_remaining.pack(side='right')
        self.percentage_of_completion = ttk.Label(self, width = 40, text=str(percent) + "%")
        self.percentage_of_completion.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE, padx = 215) 
        
        
    def create_buttonbox(self):
        """Create the application buttonbox"""
        container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=(15, 10))        

        sub_btn = ttkb.Button(
            master=container,
            text="Envoyer",
            command=self.on_submit,
            style =SUCCESS,
            width=10,
        )
        sub_btn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
        sub_btn.focus_set()

        cnl_btn = ttkb.Button(
            master=container,
            text="Cancel",
            command=self.on_cancel,
            style=DANGER,
            width=10,
        )
        cnl_btn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5) 
        
    def on_submit(self):
        """Print the contents to console and return the values."""
        print("URL:", self.URL.get())
        print("repertoire:", self.repertoire.get())        
        return self.URL.get(), self.repertoire.get()

    def on_cancel(self):
        """Cancel and close the application."""
        self.quit()
        
    def on_search(self):        
        """Search directory where to download the files."""        
        #self.repertoire = askdirectory()
        self.repertoireChoisi.set(askdirectory(
            initialdir="/",
            title="Sélectionnez un répertoire"            
            ) 
        )
        self.repertoire.set(self.repertoireChoisi.get())
        
    def on_download(self):
        """get data from the video and dl it."""
        video = YouTube(self.URL.get())
        filters = video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
        mp4_720 = filters.get_highest_resolution()
        # récupérer les infos de la vidéo ici
        # description = video.description
        # length = video.length # video length in seconds
        video.register_on_progress_callback(self.on_progress)
        mp4_720.download(self.repertoire.get())
        
        
        # filters = video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
        # mp4_1080 = filters.get_highest_resolution()
        # mp4_1080.download(self.repertoire.get(), 'test2.mp4')   
        
    def on_progress(self, stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
        """Update the progress bar."""
        total_size = stream.filesize
        bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
        self.percentage_of_completion.config(text=str((bytes_downloaded / total_size) * 100))
        


        
       
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ttkb.Window("Téléchargement de Vidéo YouTube", "superhero", resizable=(False, False))
    #app.geometry("500x400")
    DataEntryForm(app)
    app.mainloop()
        

 
    

# root = ttkb.Window(themename="darkly")

# b1 = ttkb.Button(root, text='Bouton Un', bootstyle = SUCCESS)
# b1.pack(side= LEFT, padx=5, pady = 10)

# b2 = ttkb.Button(root, text='Bouton Deux', bootstyle = (INFO, OUTLINE))
# b2.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5, pady =10) 

# root.mainloop()
```

Following exemples found here, I tried different combinations to update the progress bar from "on_progress", but I guess I am missing something obvious. (Or which should be obvious, but not to me) :-)

Thanks for your help,
Bernard

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work.
First, my syntax to register the callback was not correct. It looks like it has to be done this way:

```
video = YouTube(self.URL.get(), on_progress_callback=self.on_progress)
```

and i did not know about the progress update method

```
self.progress.update()
```

so now this is working properly. Needs to be cleaned up, but this is now a working little utility. Eventually this could help someone else:

```
import pathlib
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkbootstrap as ttkb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
import ttkbootstrap.style 
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from pytube import YouTube
import time


class DataEntryForm(ttkb.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, padding=(20,10))
        self.pack(fill =BOTH, expand=YES)
        
        #application variables
        self.repertoireChoisi = ttkb.StringVar()
        self.stuff = ttkb.IntVar()
        #self._path = pathlib.Path().absolute().as_posix()
                                                              
        #form variables
        self.URL = ttkb.StringVar(value="") 
        self.repertoire = ttkb.StringVar(value="" )     
        self.percentage_of_completion = ttkb.StringVar(value="0%")
        
        
        #form header  
        hdr_txt = "Entrez l'URL de la vidéo et le répertoire où les fichiers seront stockés"
        hdr = ttkb.Label(self, text=hdr_txt, width= 100)
        hdr.pack(fill = X, padx=10, pady=10)
        
        #form entries        
        self.create_form_entry("url", self.URL) 
        self.create_progressbar(0)
        self.create_repertoire_entry("repertoire", self.repertoire)
        self.create_buttonbox()
        
    def create_form_entry(self, label, variable):
        """Create a single form entry"""
        container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=5)

        lbl = ttkb.Label(master=container, text=label.title(), width=10)
        lbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

        ent = ttkb.Entry(master=container, textvariable=self.URL, width = 80)
        ent.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=YES)
        rep_button = ttkb.Button(
            master = container,
            text = "Télécharger",
            style=SUCCESS,
            command = self.on_download,
            width= 20
        )
        rep_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=NO)
        
    def create_repertoire_entry(self, label, variable):
        container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=5)
        lbl = ttkb.Label(master=container, text="Repertoire", width=10)
        lbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
        #self.create_form_entry("repertoire", self.repertoire)  
        ent = ttkb.Entry(master=container, width=80, textvariable=variable)        
        ent.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=NO)
        rep_button = ttkb.Button(
            master = container,
            text = "Rechercher",
            style=SUCCESS,
            command = self.on_search,
            width= 20
        )
        rep_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, fill=X, expand=NO)
                    
                    
    def create_progressbar(self, percent):
        """Create a progress bar"""
#        progress = ttkb.Frame(self,style=PRIMARY)
        #container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        self.progress = ttkb.Progressbar(self, style=PRIMARY,maximum = 100.00, mode=DETERMINATE)
        self.progress.pack(fill=X,expand=YES, pady=(15,10))
        # self.time_elapsed = ttk.Label(progress, text='00:00', font='Helvetica 12')
        # self.time_elapsed.pack(side='left')
        # self.time_scale = ttk.Scale(progress, orient='horizontal', style='info.Horizontal.TScale')
        # self.time_scale.pack(side='left', expand=True, padx=10)
        # self.time_remaining = ttk.Label(progress, text='00:00', font='Helvetica 12')
        # self.time_remaining.pack(side='right')
        self.percentage_of_completion = ttk.Label(self, width = 40, text=str(percent) + "%")
        self.percentage_of_completion.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE, padx = 215) 
        
        
    def create_buttonbox(self):
        """Create the application buttonbox"""
        container = ttkb.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=(15, 10))        

        sub_btn = ttkb.Button(
            master=container,
            text="Envoyer",
            command=self.on_submit,
            style =SUCCESS,
            width=10,
        )
        sub_btn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
        sub_btn.focus_set()

        cnl_btn = ttkb.Button(
            master=container,
            text="Cancel",
            command=self.on_cancel,
            style=DANGER,
            width=10,
        )
        cnl_btn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5) 
        
    def on_submit(self):
        """Print the contents to console and return the values."""
        print("URL:", self.URL.get())
        print("repertoire:", self.repertoire.get())        
        return self.URL.get(), self.repertoire.get()

    def on_cancel(self):
        """Cancel and close the application."""
        self.quit()
        
    def on_search(self):        
        """Search directory where to download the files."""        
        #self.repertoire = askdirectory()
        self.repertoireChoisi.set(askdirectory(
            initialdir="/",
            title="Sélectionnez un répertoire"            
            ) 
        )
        self.repertoire.set(self.repertoireChoisi.get())
        
    def on_download(self):
        """get data from the video and dl it."""
        video = YouTube(self.URL.get(), on_progress_callback=self.on_progress)
        filters = video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
        mp4_720 = filters.get_highest_resolution()
        # récupérer les infos de la vidéo ici
        # description = video.description
        # length = video.length # video length in seconds
        #video.register_on_progress_callback= self.on_progress
        mp4_720.download(self.repertoire.get())
        
        
        # filters = video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
        # mp4_1080 = filters.get_highest_resolution()
        # mp4_1080.download(self.repertoire.get(), 'test2.mp4')   
        
    def on_progress(self, stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):        
        """Update the progress bar."""
        #percent = (bytes_remaining / stream.filesize) * 100
        
        total_size = stream.filesize
        #self.stuff += chunk
        bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
        self.percentage_of_completion.config(text=str(round((bytes_downloaded / total_size) * 100,2)) + "%")
        self.progress['value'] = round((bytes_downloaded / total_size) * 100,2)
        self.progress.update()            
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ttkb.Window("Téléchargement de Vidéo YouTube", "superhero", resizable=(False, False))
    #app.geometry("500x400")
    DataEntryForm(app)
    app.mainloop()
```